# prevent dql from entity joins

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to write a DQL query that select post and join to another Entity's

here is my code

```
 $dql = '
                        SELECT p , h ,t ,m 
                        FROM App:Post p 
                        LEFT JOIN p.mentions m
                        LEFT JOIN p.tags t 
                        LEFT JOIN p.file h 
                        WHERE p.user
                        IN (
                            SELECT f FROM App:User u
                            JOIN u.followers f
                            WHERE u.id = :uid
                           )
                        OR p.user = :uid ';

        $query     = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($dql)
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->setParameters(['uid' => $user->getId()]);
        $paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);
```

but the problem is the circular reference, for example, Post -> Tags -> Posts that is used in serialization and make project freeze and shows a blank page.

[here is dump export](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/F99BY7Pt3n/)

how can I handle that Except using loop look at PersistentCollection

UPDATE ::

here is my seriallizer code

```
  $posts= [];
        foreach ($paginator as $post) {

            $posts[] = $post;

        }

        $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
        $gifts      = $serializer->toArray($posts);
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you serialize the result? How do you serialize the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use serialization groups to avoid circular reference issues. Basically, this lets your define a group (or multiple ones) to each property, then you can ask only specific(s) group(s) to be serialized.

For symfony native serializer :

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations
- https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-serialization-groups

For JMS : https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies